# PivotTable summing providing wrong values [Excel]

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have these columns in sheet1:

```
Value    Weights
-----------------
   XX         XX
   XX         XX
   XX         XX
   XX         XX
   XX         XX
...
```

I then multiply the "Value" column by the "Weights" column to get a "Weighted_Values" column:

```
Value    Weights    Weighted_Values
------------------------------------
   XX         XX                 XX
   XX         XX                 XX
   XX         XX                 XX
   XX         XX                 XX  
   XX         XX                 XX
...
```

I then sum the "Weighted_Values" column to get and record that summed value.

Now, what I am having trouble with, is repeating this process with a pivot table in Excel.

What I do is create my pivot table from the data in sheet1, and then proceed to create my "Weighted_Values" field via the "Insert Calculated Field" box, and then multiply the columns "Value" * "Weight" to create the new field "Weighted_Values". I then drag this newly created "Weighted_Values" field down to the "Values" box of the "PivotTable Fields" menu as "Sum of Weighted_Values". I see that "Values" is automatically populated in the "Rows" box, with the "Filters" and "Columns" boxes left empty. I then create my PivotTable, but see that the value for "Sum of Weighted_Values" is far larger than the summed value I reached in sheet1. Am I perhaps approaching my PivotTable workflow incorrectly? I was expecting the pivot table to show the exact same summed value I reached by just summing my "Weighted_Values" column in sheet1. Can someone please help me understand where I might have gone wrong in setting up my PivotTable? Thank you!

Here is an example of the mismatched summed values:

Sheet1:
[image]

PivotTable:
[image]

As you can see, the sums are way off. Where might I be going wrong with my pivot table?

Comment: You multiply sum of value (226) and sum of weight (3934). 226*3934 = 889084

Comment: I see, yes, but this is not the correct sum value I am looking for. I am trying to get the sum of [Weights * Value]. I am trying to use the Pivot Table to reach the sum value of 88,013. Or is this not achievable through a Pivot Table?

Comment: *Calculated Fields* always apply a `SUM` aggregation to the values in the columns referenced *prior* to applying the aggregation you specify (in this case multiplication) in the Calculated Field formula. So, in your example, the total of 889084 is obtained via taking the sum of the entries in the Value and Weight columns (226 and 3934 respectively), and then taking the product of these sums (226*3934=889084). If you are able to add your table to the Date Model then you can achieve your desired result quite simply using a Power Pivot measure.